# Sitecore: Can I assign permissions on a template to apply to all items that are defined from this template?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Can I assign permissions on a template to apply to all items that are defined from this template?

Update 1: assigning permissions to the Standard Values item is not working so far.

This is my template definition's permissions [Security Editor]:
[image]

This is my actual item's permissions [Security Editor]:
[image]

And this the actual item's permissions [Access Viewer]
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWnwp.png)

Comment: When you click on the "Write" near the actual item in Access Viewer, what is the information which is displayed on the right? It should say something "Access to this item is denied as..."

Comment: Ohh... it says: "The workflow state definition item does not allow writing. To allow writing, grant the 'workflowState:write' access right to the workflow state definition item.". Sorry, I forgot to mention about the workflow. I gave the Approved State "Workflow:Write" but still the same, I changed the state to Pending and now it says "Access to this Item is denied as no access rule allows access."

Comment: Try this: select "Pending" state in Security Editor. Click `Columns` in the ribbon and select `Workflow State Write`. Allow `RoleX` to `Workflow State Write`.

Comment: You may also try to select `Comment635...` in Content Editor, choose `VERSIONS` menu from the ribbon, click `Reset` in that ribbon and see if `Security` is different from `_Standard values` `Security`.

Comment: Granting "Workflow State Write" worked, but after so many attempts until i finally closed everything and reopened them to display granted in Access Viewer although I refreshed the items in Access Viewer several times. Thanks Marek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign permissions on `_standard values` of a template.

All the items which use this template (and which inherit from that template) will have those permissions set.

There is one exception - if the item has already some other permissions set, it will not use permissions from `_standard values`.

---

**EDIT**:

Try this: select `Pending` state in `Security Editor`. Click `Columns` in the ribbon and select `Workflow State Write`. Allow `RoleX` to `Workflow State Write`.

Comment: I already tried it, but still shows the default Read-only permissions in the Access Viewer on all the related items. Is it related to the Everyone role somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Could you be more specific? Add description what should be the permission, what have you set, some screenshot from Security Editor and Access Viewer maybe?

Comment: I have a template BlogComment, I created its standard value item and gave it write permissions for RoleX. I open the Access Viewer to view the permissions of RoleX for the actual comments items, but the write permission is still revoked.

Comment: Do the actual comment items have any other access rights set on them? Add some screenshots to your question. It should all work.